# Codeigniter creates new session row with same userdata

Tags: codeigniter, session, cookies, session-cookies

I'm working on a large-scale web app in Codeigniter with HMVC modular extensions and having problems with sessions whilst using the database (to store the sessions).

My sessions are being lost for a reason I can simply not understand.

A prime example is using the Codeigniter cart. I can successfully add items to my cart and click around the site with the items remaining in the session. However, when clicking around/pause navigating the website for ~ 3 minutes (not timed to the second) the cart losses all it's products and the session is empty. When reviewing the database, the old session is still stored in the database with the content but with a new session row created (as below).

[image: DB Sessions]

I'm running the latest version of Codeigniter with no extensions to the original Session.php class.

Below are my session config variables:

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Session Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'sess_cookie_name'        = the name you want for the cookie
| 'sess_expiration'         = the number of SECONDS you want the session to last.
|   by default sessions last 7200 seconds (two hours).  Set to zero for no expiration.
| 'sess_expire_on_close'    = Whether to cause the session to expire automatically
|   when the browser window is closed
| 'sess_encrypt_cookie'     = Whether to encrypt the cookie
| 'sess_use_database'       = Whether to save the session data to a database
| 'sess_table_name'         = The name of the session database table
| 'sess_match_ip'           = Whether to match the user's IP address when reading the session data
| 'sess_match_useragent'    = Whether to match the User Agent when reading the session data
| 'sess_time_to_update'     = how many seconds between CI refreshing Session Information
|
*/
$config['sess_cookie_name']     = 'myhmvc_session';
$config['sess_expiration']      = 7200;
$config['sess_expire_on_close'] = FALSE;
$config['sess_encrypt_cookie']  = FALSE;
$config['sess_use_database']    = TRUE;
$config['sess_table_name']      = 'users_sessions';
$config['sess_match_ip']        = TRUE;
$config['sess_match_useragent'] = TRUE;
$config['sess_time_to_update']  = 300;

/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| Cookie Related Variables
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| 'cookie_prefix' = Set a prefix if you need to avoid collisions
| 'cookie_domain' = Set to .your-domain.com for site-wide cookies
| 'cookie_path'   =  Typically will be a forward slash
| 'cookie_secure' =  Cookies will only be set if a secure HTTPS connection exists.
|
*/
$config['cookie_prefix']    = "my";
$config['cookie_domain']    = "myhmvc.co.uk";
$config['cookie_path']  = "/";
$config['cookie_secure']    = FALSE;
```

Any help is greatly appreciated, willing to try anything at this stage.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've still not gotten round to understanding Codeigniter's issue with sessions but from reading other posts there's quite an issue with default sessions.

I've installed the Session Driver seen here:
http://getsparks.org/packages/session-driver/versions/HEAD/show

Which has now fixed the issue.

I hope this helps others who have had similar problems.